# SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list in discord.js

Tags: node.js

when i run this eval command i get this error

> SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
> at Object.exports.run (/home/container/commands/eval.js:12:25)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjFak.png

```
     exports.run = async (client, message, args, level) => { // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
      const code = args.join(" ");
      try {
        const evaled = eval(code);
        const clean = await client.clean(client, evaled);
        message.channel.send(`\`\`\`js\n${clean}\n\`\`\``);
      } catch (err) {
        message.channel.send(`\`ERROR\` \`\`\`xl\n${await client.clean(client, err)}\n\`\`\``);
      }
    };
```

Comment: What is the value of `args` & `code`. Chances are that the `eval`ed code is invalid.

Comment: what should it be

Comment: No idea. It depends what you are trying to do. but without knowing what the  value of `code` is there's no way to know whether it is the problem or not.

Comment: thats all the code as its an eval command the rest is the command handler

Comment: The problem is the value that is being passed to `eval`. Try debugging the code and let us know what value you have for the `code` variable before it's passed to `eval`

Comment: Iv found the issue thank you for your help